# How can I sort a list with data from another list adding at the end?

Tags: java, list, sorting

*Implement an instance method called sort, which assuming the list contains values greater than 0
and all its elements are different, it returns a new ordered list
using the following strategy: “select the minor element from the list and place it
at the end of the results list ”. Please note that the original list should NOT
be modified.*

```
    public IntegerLinkedList sort(IntegerLinkedList l){
        IntegerLinkedList l2 = new IntegerLinkedList ();
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int min_prev = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int pos;
        for (int i=0; i<l.length(); i++){
            pos=0;          
            while (pos<l.length()) {
                if ((l.element(pos) < min) & (l.element(pos) > min_prev)){                  
                    min = l.element(pos);
                }
                pos++;
            }                       
            min_prev=min;
            l2.AddAtTheEnd(min);
        }
        return l2;
}
List: 2 -> 8 -> 4 -> 6 -> 1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 9 -> 5 -> 10
```

First time seeing list in Java at university. So my problem is I can't stop adding 1 to l2 all the time. This code is an idea of what i had but it returns a 10-lenght list full of 1. There's a time when 1 isn't smaller than 1 nor bigger than 1. I need to "avoid" the last smallest added number so I can add the others bigger than min.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the first run of the for-loop, `min` is 1. It never gets set to anything else: `(l.element(pos) < 1)` is false for all elements except 1.

You need to reset the value of `min` in every run of the loop.

```
    for (int i=0; i<l.length(); i++){
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        pos=0;          
        while (pos<l.length()) {
```